# Variable declared inside module not is undefined after compilation

Tags: angularjs, typescript, typescript1.6

I have declared the following files

**app.types.ts**

```
/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
module App{
    export var Module =     "website";
    //---------------Controller Base Types---------------
    export interface IScope extends ng.IScope {
        events: Controller;
    }
    export class Controller{
        protected scope: IScope;
        static id       : string;
        constructor($scope: IScope,controllerId:  string){
            this.scope        =     $scope;
            this.scope.events =     this;
            Controller.id                =      controllerId;
        }
    }
}
```

**app.ts**

```
    /// /// <reference path="app.types.ts"/>
    module App {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module(Module, [
        // Angular modules
        'ngMessages','ngAnimate','ngTouch','ngAria','ngSanitize',
        // Custom modules
        'ui.router','ui.bootstrap','ui.bootstrap.tpls'
        // 3rd Party Modules
    ]);
}
```

The code compiles to Js without errors but the variable Module is undefined across the file.

I also tried using App.Module but still the variable was undefined

Update :
I have check the app.types.js is inserted in the html before app.js. There generated Js files seem to be incorrect.

```js
//App.js
(function(){/// <reference path="app.types.ts"/>
var App;
(function (App) {
    "use strict";
    var app = angular.module(App.Module, [
        // Angular modules
        'ngMessages', 'ngAnimate', 'ngTouch', 'ngAria', 'ngSanitize',
        // Custom modules
        'ui.router', 'ui.bootstrap', 'ui.bootstrap.tpls'
    ]);
})(App || (App = {}));
}());
```

```js
//App.types.js
(function(){/// <reference path="../../typings/tsd.d.ts"/>
var App;
(function (App) {
    App.Module = "website";
    var Controller = (function () {
        function Controller($scope, controllerId) {
            this.scope = $scope;
            this.scope.events = this;
            Controller.id = controllerId;
        }
        return Controller;
    })();
    App.Controller = Controller;
})(App || (App = {}));
}());
```

Answer (score 0):

You should add:

```
/// <reference path="relative/path/to/app.types.ts"/>
```

to your `app.ts` file. If I'm not mistaken you should see that the order of your scripts is not correct - i.e. `app.types.js` is loaded after `app.js`.